# Sanity check on setting variable reference?

Tags: c#, reference

In my application my main form is a singleton class `MainForm.Instance`. It has a property, that has a property, etc. To save my fingers from typing it out in a class I am working on I have set a local reference to the property.

```
MyClass myClassInst = MainForm.Instance.MyProperty.AProperty.TheProperty;
```

With this local reference I do all of my work

```
myClassInst.AnInt = 4;
myClassInst.AThing = newValue;
// ... etc
```

Say I have now created a new instance of `MyClass` and want to set the `MainForm.Instance....` equal to it. *Do I need to reset my local reference to the new object?*

```
MyClass newClassInst = new MyClass();
MainForm.Instance.MyProperty.AProperty.TheProperty = newClassInst;

// Do I need to do this?
myClassInst = newClassInst;

// What about this?
myClassInst = MainForm.Instance.MyProperty.AProperty.TheProperty;
```

*Also, did I use the right vocabulary when refering to what I call "my local reference"?*

---

Now I "know" I do not need to do this, but I have thoroughly confused myself. `myClassInst` should point to the memory location that holds a `MyClass` object, no matter if the object itself changes `myClassInst` should always refer to it as long as it exists, correct?

---

**EDIT:** I think I just found a much more eloquent way to solve my issue outlined above. As stated I have some local reference along the lines of

```
MyClass myClassInst = MainForm.Instance.MyProperty.AProperty.TheProperty;
```

But this is actually implemented as a property in my application

```
private MyClass MyClassInst { get; set; } = ...;
```

Instead of worrying about when to "reset" `myClassInst` to point to a new reference I can just modify the property to return or modify the current reference of `MainForm.Instance...`

```
private MyClass MyClassInst
{
    get { return MainForm.Instance.MyProperty.AProperty.TheProperty; }
    set { MainForm.Instance.MyProperty.AProperty.TheProperty = value; }
}
```

This property will then return whatever `TheProperty` currently references, and inturn will assign the current reference `TheProperty` points to.

This reminds me of `using` aliasing for class names...

```
using ShortName = ANameSpace.BNameSpace.AReallyRidiculouslyLongClassName;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myClassInst` holds the same reference as `TheProperty`, i.e. they both point to the same object.

```
myClassInst -------------> Object
                             ^
                             |
TheProperty -----------------+
```

If you assign a new object to `TheProperty`, then `myClassInst` still references the old object. Why should it point to the new object?

```
myClassInst -------------> Object

TheProperty -------------> new object
```

Note: neither `myClassInst` nor `TheProperty` are the object. They are references to an object, like arrows pointing to something.

But you could reference `AProperty` instead.

```
MyAClass aProp = MainForm.Instance.MyProperty.AProperty;
aProp.TheProperty.AnInt = 4;
MyClass newClassInst = new MyClass{ AnInt = 5 };
MainForm.Instance.MyProperty.AProperty.TheProperty = newClassInst;

// Now, since AProperty didn't change, you can reference the new object
Console.WriteLine(aProp.TheProperty.AnInt); // Prints 5
```

Comment: Ahhh. So in my original explanation of why I think I don't need to do this I assumed that the new instance would located in the same memory location that the two references reference. But what actually happens is that the new object is created and placed in a `new` memory location, thus when I set the `MainForm.Instance...` the second reference now points to the memory location of the old `MyClass` instance.

Comment: I know this question is basically over but I had a good idea on how to solve my (non)"issue". It is outlined in an edit to the OP above. Could you review it and maybe give me your quick thoughts on it?

Comment: This is the difference between caching a value and calculating it on the fly. The property `MyClassInst` is a bit dangerous, because it might not do what you expect. Usually if you set a value, you expect to later read the same value again. But if one of these intermediate references has been changed meanwhile, you might get out something different than you put in. It would be more understandable to have a pair of methods with speaking names like `GetCurrentMyClassInst` `SetCurrentMyClassInst`, making clear that some logic is involved.

Comment: I do understand that danger, but in my application I don't think it is an issue. Its inferred that `MainForm.Instance...TheProperty` is the one and only object that is important. I just needed a nice way to reference it without using 50 characters. // Though it might be worth it to create the methods for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to do one or the other of those two things.

Your `myClassInst` is a *copy* of a *reference* to an *instance*. When you create a new instance, you need to update all references to point to the new instance.

Updates to the *reference* that you copied originally do not propagate to copies of that reference.